# How to save a qr code image as a model field in Django

Tags: django, django-models, qr-code

I want to add a qr code image field to my 'Person' model. The data of the qr code will come from the user_id and will store its profile page – for example, user 1234 will have the qr code that contains siteurl.com/1234.

I began by creating the image field, but I am not sure as to where to go from there. Any help would be appreciated!

Models:

```
from django.db import models
import uuid


class Person(models.Model):
    user_id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()
    number_of_guests = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    qrcode_image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='qr_code_images',
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return " ".join([self.first_name, self.last_name, str(self.user_id)])
```

Comment: You can look into the [`post_save` signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/#post-save) of django and create the qr code once a new `Person` is created. Once you have the qr image, store it in your `qrcode_image` attribute.

Comment: QR codes are trivially created from strings, and there are plenty of libraries that will do this in Django and Python - see for example https://django-qr-code.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. There's no need to store the QR image itself.

Comment: I tried that option beforehand – I was stuck because I couldn't create a text qr code from a data field in a model. Here's how text qr codes are created: 
{% qr_from_text "Hello World!" size="T" %}
How can I make the text a field in my Person model?

Comment: Why can't you do `{% qr_from_text my_instance.my_field size="T" %}` for example?

Comment: I could do that, but I want my data to be the entire url path.

Comment: Ah, I think I found a solution – I made an override of `save` to create a url field, which I then made into a qr code. Thanks for the help :)